# Why do I keep getting this error message to install pods on react native when I've already done so?

Tags: react-native

% npx pod-install ios

Scanning for pods...
1.11.3

> pod install

Auto-linking React Native modules for target `SocialGame`: BVLinearGradient,

RNCMaskedView, RNCPushNotificationIOS, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNScreens,

RNVectorIcons, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-video

Analyzing dependencies

Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party- podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`

Fetching podspec for `RCT-Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party- podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`

Fetching podspec for `boost` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party- podspecs/boost.podspec`

Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party- podspecs/glog.podspec`

Downloading dependencies

Installing BVLinearGradient (2.5.6)

Installing CocoaAsyncSocket (7.6.5)

Installing DoubleConversion (1.1.6)

Installing FBLazyVector (0.66.1)

Installing FBReactNativeSpec (0.66.1)

Installing Flipper (0.99.0)

Installing Flipper-Boost-iOSX (1.76.0.1.11)

Installing Flipper-DoubleConversion (3.1.7)

Installing Flipper-Fmt (7.1.7)

Installing Flipper-Folly (2.6.7)

Installing Flipper-Glog (0.3.6)

Installing Flipper-PeerTalk (0.0.4)

Installing Flipper-RSocket (1.4.3)

Installing FlipperKit (0.99.0)

Installing OpenSSL-Universal (1.1.180)

Installing RCT-Folly (2021.06.28.00-v2)

Installing RCTRequired (0.66.1)

Installing RCTTypeSafety (0.66.1)

Installing RNCMaskedView (0.1.11)

Installing RNCPushNotificationIOS (1.10.1)

Installing RNGestureHandler (1.10.3)

Installing RNReanimated (2.7.0)

Installing RNScreens (3.13.1)

Installing RNVectorIcons (8.1.0)

Installing React (0.66.1)

Installing React-Core (0.66.1)

Installing React-CoreModules (0.66.1)

Installing React-RCTActionSheet (0.66.1)

Installing React-RCTAnimation (0.66.1)

Installing React-RCTBlob (0.66.1)

Installing React-RCTImage (0.66.1)

Installing React-RCTLinking (0.66.1)

Installing React-RCTNetwork (0.66.1)

Installing React-RCTSettings (0.66.1)

Installing React-RCTText (0.66.1)

Installing React-RCTVibration (0.66.1)

Installing React-callinvoker (0.66.1)

Installing React-cxxreact (0.66.1)

Installing React-jsi (0.66.1)

Installing React-jsiexecutor (0.66.1)

Installing React-jsinspector (0.66.1)

Installing React-logger (0.66.1)

Installing React-perflogger (0.66.1)

Installing React-runtimeexecutor (0.66.1)

Installing ReactCommon (0.66.1)

Installing Yoga (1.14.0)

Installing YogaKit (1.18.1)

Installing boost (1.76.0)

Installing fmt (6.2.1)

Installing glog (0.3.5)

Installing libevent (2.1.12)

Installing react-native-safe-area-context (3.4.1)

Installing react-native-video (5.2.0)

Generating Pods project

Integrating client project

Pod installation complete! There are 62 dependencies from the Podfile and 53 total pods installed.

% yarn ios

yarn run v1.22.18

warning ../../../../../../package.json: No license field

$ react-native run-ios

**error Could not find the following native modules: RNCMaskedView 2, RNCPushNotificationIOS 2, RNGestureHandler 3, BVLinearGradient 2, RNReanimated 2, RNScreens 2, RNVectorIcons 2. Did you forget to run "pod install"**

Comment: Did you run `yarn` before running `npx pod-install`? Perhaps delete the node_modules folder, the yarn.lock file, the package-lock.json file (if it exists) and the Podfile.lock file and then run `yarn`, followed by `npx pod-install`. Then see if it works?